# Twitch Streamlabs Chat box emotes duping [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css, stream, chat, twitch

So, I'm trying to configure a custom HTML/CSS chatbox on Stream Labs. Everything work fine, except the emotes. They appear duped on the chat box, as shown on the screenshot. It looks like it's trying to auto duplicate to fill the space on the chat box.

[Emotes duplicating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gITQ1.png)

HTML

```
<div id="log-wrapper" class="sl__chat__layout"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="chatlist_item">
  <div data-from="{from}" data-id="{messageId}" class="log-wrapper--item">
    <span class="item-meta">
        <span class="badges"></span>
      {from}
    </span>
    <span class="item-message">{message}</span>
  </div>
</script>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  color: #fff;
}

.badges {
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.badges * {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#log-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
}

.log-wrapper--item {
  max-width: 350px;
  word-break: break-word;
    margin: 5px 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  animation: fadein .2s, fadeOut 0.5s ease {message_hide_delay} forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadein .2s, fadeOut 0.5s ease {message_hide_delay} forwards;
}

.item-meta {
    top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  background: #1A74A8;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
}

.item-message {
    padding: 10px 10px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  width: fit-content;
  min-width: 240px;
  border: 3px solid #3c2975;
  border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(40, 20, 20, 0.5);
}

#log .emote {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 0.4em 0.2em;
    position: relative;
}

#log .emote img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
}


#log-wrapper > div.deleted {
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        transform: translatey(10px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I've messed around some things but no success on fixing it. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I happened to come across this by chance, so I started messing around with the HTML and CSS that you have here and for some reason, I don't understand why, but if you delete the word "wrapper" from the HTML and the CSS it will fix the duping problem. I don't get why it fixes the issue but it does.